# Why is this not a geometric distribution?

Tags: statistics

> > A recruiting firm finds that 20% of the applications are fluent in both English and French. Applicants are selected randomly from a pool and interviewed sequentially. Find the probability that at least five applicants are interviewed before finding the first applicant who is fluent in both English and French

The answer for this question is $(0.8)^5$. However, since the questions asks for the probability that at least 5 applicants are interviewed *before* finding the first applicant, wouldn't this be a geometric distribution, so $(0.8)^5 (0.2)$?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: *At least* five, not *exactly* five.

Answer (score 1):

It is a geometric distribution.

note $(0.8)^5 \times 0.2$ is exactly 5. You want $P(X\geq 5)$ for you which, if you do the sum

$0.8^5 \times 0.2 + 0.8^6\times 0.2 + 0.8^7\times 0.2 ... = $

You get $0.8^5$ but it'd be easier just observing greater equal to 5 means first 5 needs to be 'fails', i.e. $0.8^5$